# Computing class numbers in a range

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let be $\mathcal{G} : \mathbb{N}^{*^2} \to \mathbb{N}$ a function, defined be

$$ \mathcal{G}(a,b) = \#\{ d | 0 < d \le a, h(d) = b \} $$

Where $h(d)$ is the class number of the real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$.

For example, computing $\mathcal{G}(787, 3)$, we obtain:

$$G(787,3) = \#\{ d | 0 < d \le 787, h(d) = 3\}  \Rightarrow $$ $$\mathcal{G}(787,3) = \#\{229, 257, 316, 321, 469, 473, 568, 733 \} \Rightarrow $$ $$ \boxed{\mathcal{G}(787,3) = 8}$$

When we consider the function

$$\mathcal{D}(\ell) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  \mathcal{G}(\ell,k)$$

(a) Does $\mathcal{D}(\ell) < \infty  \ \forall \ell \in \mathbb{N}^{*}?$

(b) If the item above is true, what about the convergence of the sequence below?

$$ \sum\limits_{\ell=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\delta(\mathcal{D}(\ell))} $$

Where
$$ \delta(x) = \left\{  \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{if $x = 0$};\\
        x & \mbox{if $x > 0$}.\end{array} \right. $$

Comment: With your definition $\mathcal{D}(\ell) = \ell$. Also the sum starts at $k=1$, and it ends with the Minkowski's bound.

Comment: Yes, I fixed this